# Join JSON String

Tags: javascript

Is there a particular way to join each individual block of string with `|` that way it's

`9000234|Test NPC|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|` excluding `isEnabled.` I don't want the other block merging with each other either. I'm not exactly sure how I would go about this.

```
    "100_npc": {
        "uniqueId": 9000234,
        "username": "Test NPC",
        "itemsObj": {"colour": 0, "head": 0, "face": 0, "body": 0, "neck": 0, "hand": 0, "feet": 0, "flag": 0, "photo": 0},
        "isEnabled": true
    },
    "101_npc": {
        "uniqueId": 9000251,
        "username": "Pelican",
        "itemsObj": {"colour": 0, "head": 0, "face": 0, "body": 0, "neck": 0, "hand": 0, "feet": 0, "flag": 0, "photo": 0},
        "isEnabled": true
    }
}
```

Comment: How many layers of nesting do you have to handle?

Comment: You'll need to pin down the order of those columns.

Comment: Output as array or newline separated file?

Comment: I tried pushing it out as an array but it would merge altogether and that's not what I wanted.

Comment: So what is that you wanted? The desired output is still unclear. How would you know that a block is related to `100_npc`, `101_npc` or any other?

Comment: I want it to output `9000234|Test NPC|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|` splitting the values with `|` and the same way for the 2nd block.

Comment: @Zesty Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/sfmtrjhd/

Comment: You provided two objects. I still don't get it... I presume that your input is: `"100_npc"` and as response you want the .... pipe | separated string, right?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do such a thing? You've already got perfectly good JSON, a format far easier to parse and subsequently work with.

Comment: Pointy has a good point

Comment: I know its bad practice but the Club Penguin protocol builds the player strings like that splitting them with `|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to output what you are asking for: ([playground](https://playcode.io/1458689))

```js
    let data = {
      '100_npc': {
        uniqueId: 9000234,
        username: 'Test NPC',
        itemsObj: {
          colour: 0,
          head: 0,
          face: 0,
          body: 0,
          neck: 0,
          hand: 0,
          feet: 0,
          flag: 0,
          photo: 0,
        },
        isEnabled: true,
      },
      '101_npc': {
        uniqueId: 9000251,
        username: 'Pelican',
        itemsObj: {
          colour: 0,
          head: 0,
          face: 0,
          body: 0,
          neck: 0,
          hand: 0,
          feet: 0,
          flag: 0,
          photo: 0,
        },
        isEnabled: true,
      },
    };
    
    let result = [];
    
    for (let key in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        let item = data[key];
        let arr = [item.uniqueId, item.username];
        for (let objKey in item.itemsObj) {
          arr.push(item.itemsObj[objKey]);
        }
        result.push(arr.join('|'));
      }
    }
    
    console.log(result.join('\n'));
```

Comment: Yup exactly how I want it

Comment: Thanks again! I was able to rewrite this in ActionScript and it works exactly how it's suppose to.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to search only for a specific property name like "npc_100"

```js
const data =  {  
  "100_npc": {"uniqueId": 9000234,"username": "Test NPC","itemsObj": {"colour": 0, "head": 0, "face": 0, "body": 0, "neck": 0, "hand": 0, "feet": 0, "flag": 0, "photo": 0},"isEnabled": true},
  "101_npc": {"uniqueId": 9000251,"username": "Pelican","itemsObj": {"colour": 0, "head": 0, "face": 0, "body": 0, "neck": 0, "hand": 0, "feet": 0, "flag": 0, "photo": 0},"isEnabled": true}
};


const prop = "100_npc";

const result = Object.entries(data[prop]).reduce((a, [k, v]) => 
  (k !== "isEnabled" && a.push(k==="itemsObj" ? Object.values(v) : v), a)
, []).flat().join("|");

console.log(result)
```

For a *file* output:

```js
const data =  {  
  "100_npc": {"uniqueId": 9000234,"username": "Test NPC","itemsObj": {"colour": 0, "head": 0, "face": 0, "body": 0, "neck": 0, "hand": 0, "feet": 0, "flag": 0, "photo": 0},"isEnabled": true},
  "101_npc": {"uniqueId": 9000251,"username": "Pelican","itemsObj": {"colour": 0, "head": 0, "face": 0, "body": 0, "neck": 0, "hand": 0, "feet": 0, "flag": 0, "photo": 0},"isEnabled": true}
};

const result = Object.values(data).map(entry => Object.entries(entry).reduce((a, [k, v]) => 
  (k !== "isEnabled" && a.push(k==="itemsObj" ? Object.values(v) : v), a)
, []).flat().join("|")).join("\n");

console.log(result)
```